# Networking library compatible C++ and Java

Tags: c++, java, android, networking

There is any networking library like **eNet** compatible with *Java* and *C++*?

'm trying to find a way to communicate an Android game in Java with a C + + server, but I prefer to use a network library instead raw sockets.

I've found a [java-enet](https://github.com/csm/java-enet), but I don't know if it's a mature project or compatible with eNet C version.

Comment: Can't you just use eNet with C++ and some Java networking library on the Java side? How would that not be compatible network-wise? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: This is the problem. ENet's purpose is to provide a relatively thin, simple and robust network communication layer on top of UDP (User Datagram Protocol). The primary feature it provides is optional reliable, in-order delivery of packets. So I've to implement the ENet protocol to be compatible. I'm going to try if java-enet are compatible with eNet 1.3.x protocol.  I wish there was a bookstore like eNet functional in both languages.

Comment: You really want to use eNet, don't you? Well, I didn't want to write an answer because it really doesn't answer your question directly, but it is possible to compile eNet as an Android module and use it inside any Java application through JNI. I have managed to successfully build the library and initialize it in a simple Android HelloWorld app. **Pros**: you are using essentially the same version of eNet both server- and client-side. **Cons**: the compiling to an Android compatible module requires some code acrobatics. More info here: http://pastebin.com/gLWDuGu1

Comment: @VladimirMitrovic Post that as an answer. :) It might not directly answer the question but it does respond to fabregot's desire.

Comment: @jonathan I can't, I don't have access to a computing device with a physical keyboard (exams time results in me going cold turkey on the internet stuff so I locked it away :)). When I'm done with school work in a couple of weeks, I'll try to implement a simple client app using jni wrapped enet module and if I succeed, I'll post the full steps and source code here, if it's allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [ICE](http://zeroc.com/index.html). It's cross platform network middleware, which is quite powerful. It has C++ and Java binds, also with android support IIRC.